# How to avoid to cache _Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I use an attribute for setting the _Layout in my project and I use some Caching attribute to cache some data.

My custom Layout attribute code is as follows:

```
public class CustomLayoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        string layoutName = "";
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            switch (SystemInfo.Theme)
            {
                case 1:
                    layoutName = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Themes/B/_LayoutMain-En.cshtml";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    layoutName = "~/Views/Shared/Layouts/Themes/A/_LayoutMain-En.cshtml";
                    break;
                }
            }

            viewResult.MasterName = layoutName;
        }
    }
}
```

The Layout and the caching attribute looks like this on the Controller Action method:

```
[CustomLayout]
[OutputCache(Duration = 60 * 10, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByCustom = "lang")]
public ActionResult Index() { }
```

How to disable caching for `_Layout`?

Comment: Are you asking about the same thing in your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33970536/how-to-cache-action-when-layout-is-daynamic)?

Comment: they are not same question .